# How many buildings are there in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm interested in a ballpark estimate of how many buildings there currently are in total in OpenStreetMap.  I'd also like to know roughly how many buildings in total there are in the world, so I can calculate the coverage, but it's mostly the total count that I'm after.

I've attempted to download the [Planet.osm](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) data file but the uncompressed version is too large for my computer, so I haven't been able to spin it up and run the analysis myself.

I'm not using any GIS software, but could do so if there's a path to establishing the answer. I was anticipating that the answer could be found using Clojure, Python or by loading the data into a PostGIS instance.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure why this has been downvoted but I'd love to know so I can improve the question?  It would be less vague if I asked for the precise number, would that be more suitable?

Comment: You show no effort of your own and your question is unclear (what GIS software are you using)

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with more information.

Comment: looks like https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Ohsome_Dashboard could help you answer

Comment: Or the number of OSM elements with a [building key](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:building): https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/building

Comment: Ah thank you @scai that's just what i'm looking for.

Comment: @IanTurton thank you for sharing that link, it will allow to perform some deeper analysis.

Comment: I imported planet osm pbf into a PostgreSQL database. It took a week for the full import and I got 39403971

Answer (score 3):

From the link kindly provided by @scai, the answer appears to be just under 400m.

https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/building